# how to display absolute div outside container with overflow-x auto

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to set header menu that contains several items with dropdown menu. it works fine when there are few items that fit in screen but when I add an horizontal scrollbar (overflow-x: auto) to the header (in case there are many menu items), dropdowns elements are "stuck" inside header container.

(PS: I want the horizontal scroll bar only on the header not all page)

example :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .body {
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .item {
        position:relative;
      }
      .sub-item {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 5px;
        right: 0;
      }
      .head {
        display:flex; 
        gap:1rem; 
        padding: 10px; 
        border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="head">
        <div>item_1</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div>item_2</div>
          <div class="sub-item">sub item</div>
        </div>
        <div>item_3</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div>item_4</div>
          <div class="sub-item">sub item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elnem!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

so to add a scroll bar I put `overflow-x: auto;` inside class `head` but the dropdown items are hidden inside `head` container